# TypeError when Defining Variable

Tags: python, argv

I am running a proven code and the function brings back a type error when running the defined function.

The code is as following:

```
def print_two_again(arg1, arg2):
     print "arg1: %s, arg2: &s" % (arg1, arg2)

print_two_again("Zed", "Shaw")
```

The output is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "ex18.py", line 15, in <module>
        print_two_again("Zed", "Shaw")
    File "ex18.py", line 6, in print_two_again
        print "arg1: %s, arg2: &s" % (arg1, arg2)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: What do you mean with "proven code"?

Comment: You're trying to format with a `&` instead of a `%`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo there:

```
   print "arg1: %s, arg2: &s" % (arg1, arg2)
```

`&s` should be `%s`.

Python is telling you that on the message `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`, but in its very own way.

Read it like this: '*you told me to format this string, and you gave me two arguments for that.  But, when I look at the string, I see only one spot for values*'.  Here, the spots for values are marked by the `%` character and the format specification character (`s`, in this case).